# Positioning to the center of hyperlink parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `hyperlink` that looks like so:

```
<a id="addNew" class="newEvent" href="/html/addNew.html">
    <label class="add">+</label>    
</a>
```

The CSS for these:

```
.newEvent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6vw;    
    right: 6vw;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #ce0808;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;    
    align-content: center;
}

.add {
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
```

For no apparent reason the `+` sign is aligned to the left. 
Note that I tried those `text-align`, `margin: 0 auto` and so on solutions I found online, but none of them worked, the best I got was center horizontally, but aligned to the top.  I require assistance to finally center that `+` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had ommited the display type. I assume you wanted to use flexbox based on `align-items`?

```css
.newEvent {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 6vw;
  right: 6vw;
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #ce0808;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.add {
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a id="addNew" class="newEvent" href="/html/addNew.html">
  <label class="add">+</label>
</a>
```

Comment: nice. By the way, what's with the blue underline? I get that here in my editor as well as on StackOverflow

Comment: @agiro Because `.newEvent` is an anchor tag, it gets text-decoration by default from browser. You can remove this, as I have done in the updated snippet.

Comment: And it's the solution I was after. Thanks for your help! 
I go and google `display`, because I haven't heard about it lol. Accepting answer in 7 mins...

Comment: No problem. This link is excellent: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for the share. Now I know what will I read for evening tale xd

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you tried the `text-align` property, but it is working just fine.

**Working demo**

```css
.newEvent {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6vw;    
    right: 6vw;
    height: 10vw;
    width: 10vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #ce0808;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;    
    text-align: center;
}

.add {
    font-size: 6vw;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a id="addNew" class="newEvent" href="/html/addNew.html">
    <label class="add">+</label>    
</a>
```